# Creating a grab-bag (collection) of original references to objects

Tags: c#, memory-management, collections, reference

I'm looking for a type/method of collection where I can add an object to a group of objects, then separately change the attributes of that object, and have those changes reflected in the object within the collection.

I've heard that List<T> adds values by reference, so I figured that the reference would be to the same object.  In other words, I assumed:

```
List<string> valuesList = new List<string>();
string initialValue = "Alpha";
valuesList.Add(initialValue);

initialValue = "Bravo";
bool incorrectAssumption = (valuesList[0] == "Bravo");
```

I had hoped that 'valuesList' would then contain the new value, "Bravo."  Tried it out and I realized that the List *copies* the reference, it doesn't absorb it, so valueList still only has the "Alpha" value.  Are there any ways to use a collection as a legitimate handful of the objects they contain?

And in case it helps to see the actual business need....

```
List<BaseWidget> widgets = new List<BaseWidget>();

DerivedWidget specialWidget = new DerivedWidget();
DerivedWidget extraSpecialWidget = new DerivedWidget();

widgets.Add(specialWidget);
widgets.Add(extraSpecialWidget);

specialWidget.Run();
extraSpecialWidget.Run();

if (!widgets.Any(x => x.RunSuccessfully)) return false;
```

(Where the Run() method sets the RunSuccessfully property, which I'd like to have reflected in the 'widgets' list.)

============================================================================

**UPDATE**

As it's been pointed out in the answers and comments, there's a bit of a discrepancy between the business need mock-up and the dry-run example.  I'll condense the life-lesson into this: it seems `List<objects>` have their changes tracked, whereas `List<values>` don't.

Comment: You did not "change the attributes of that object" in your first example, you just changed a local variable to refer to a different object. Your description of what List<T> does ("the reference would be to the same object") is correct. The second example should work just fine, did you try it?

Comment: Your code copied a reference into the list and then you created a new reference.  If the String class had a hypothetical "Content" property then initialValue.Content = "Bravo" would also change the string in the list.  But it doesn't have one, strings are immutable.  Solve your problem by putting an object of your own class in the list, a class with such a Content property.

Comment: (facepalm) I was just testing the general principle of the behavior with strings, but you're right, a list of *objects* (classes) does work like it should. Damn, that is embarrassing.  Not sure if this is still a valid question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All references to non-value types will be passed by reference, `List<T>` or not.  <s>String is a value type, however, and will always be passed by value</s>.  They are also immutable, so any time you change one you're actually creating a new String.

For your example, you could create a wrapper type to contain your string, and store this in your `List<T>`.

It seems that your actual business case should work properly, unless they are declared as structs.

Comment: @nsinreal My mistake.  They behave like value types due to their immutability, so I assumed without looking it up.  It turns out they're passed by reference as they can be too large for the stack.

Comment: Pass by reference isn't the term you're looking for (I know OP did it too). Pass by reference would be using `ref` or `out`, and that could indeed do something similar to what OP expects (e.g. `void Zero(ref int a) { a = 0; }` does change `x` in `Zero(ref x);`).

Comment: @delnan I know that 'pass by reference' refers to using the `ref` keyword, but I was under the impression that it also referred to the way reference types are passed to methods by default.  Is there another term for this, or should I just say that the type concerned is a reference type?

Comment: That impression is understandable as this abuse of terminology is somewhat common, but it's both against decades of CS tradition and harmful in that is removes a useful distinction. Saying the type is a reference type is probably best. Other languages' communities have created new terms for this style of argument passing but I haven't seen them used for C#. You could say that references are passed by value (a phrasing I've seen applied to Java).

Comment: Well, I'm embarrassed. I probably should have written a unit test instead of just imitating the behavior with strings. You're right that there doesn't seem to be a problem in my implementation, just in how I set up the dry-run.  Oops....

Answer (score 1):

Well. It seems that you don't understand what happens really. Here is great article about [.net type internals](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20481/NET-Type-Internals-From-a-Microsoft-CLR-Perspecti).

Shortly, what happens in your example with strings:

1. You create list
2. You create variable initialValue of string type. Value of this variable stores in special local variables container. Because string is reference type, in container of local variables it contained as a pointer to object.
3. You create new string "Alpha", storing it in heap, and assign pointer (to this string) to your local variable.
4. Then you are adding object to list. In your List this object stored as pointer to somewhere.
5. Then you are changing content of local variable 'initialValue' by assign it to pointer to another string. So, now in local variable 'initialValue' is one pointer, in list is another pointer.

Well, what about solutions?

1. Wrap your string to some another class. Like this:

   ```
   class Wrapper<T> {
       public T Content {get;set;}

   public Wrapper(T content) {
       Content = content;
       }
   }
   ```

   Usage:

   ```
   void Main()
   {
       var valuesList = new List<Wrapper<string>>();
       var initialValue = new Wrapper<string>("Alpha");
       valuesList.Add(initialValue);

       initialValue.Content = "Bravo";

       Console.WriteLine(valuesList[0].Content);
   }
   ```

   A bit ugly syntax.
2. Use clojures:

   ```
   void Main()
   {
       List<Func<string>> valuesList = new List<Func<string>>();
       string initialValue = "Alpha";
       valuesList.Add(() => initialValue);

       initialValue = "Bravo";
       Console.WriteLine(valuesList[0]() == "Bravo");
   }
   ```